# Access VBA - checklist database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am relatively new to Access but have a little experience on VBA. I am trying to create a database of daily work checklists with various questions for different clients. A friend suggested I create a dynamic form through VBA that will create multiple questions in textboxes every time a client is selected from a dropdown box. I am trying to create textboxes in VBA but Im getting an error message saying I need to be in design mode to create text boxes.

I lifted the below code from the internet, is it possible to activate the design view once the code is running as I need to start in form view to click the drop-down or if anyone has a suggestion for another way I'd appreciate it too. Thanks

```
Private Sub ComClient_AfterUpdate()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim ctrl As Control, ctlText As Control, CtlLabel As Control
    Dim intDataX As Integer, intDataY As Integer
    Dim intLabelX As Integer, intLabelY As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    count = RecordCount

    For x = 1 To count
    Set ctrl = CreateControl("TestControlCreate", acTextBox, acDetail, , "", 0 + (x * 300), 0, 300, 240)

    frm.RecordSource = "Get_Questions"

    ctrl.ControlName = "TxtBx" & x

    Set ctlText = CreateControl("Question " & x, acTextBox, , "", "", _
        intDataX, intDataY)

    Set CtlLabel = CreateControl(frm.Name, acLabel, , _
         ctlText.Name, "NewLabel", intLabelX, intLabelY)

    DoCmd.Restore

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in MS Access can be somewhat frustrating, because its version of forms, etc. is not the full-blown SDK that you got in VB6.  Therefore, a lot of VB forms code you find on the Internet will not work.

The approach I would recommend is to create a form laid out (that is you this by hand) with the maximum number checkboxes you think you will possibly need, and use VBA code to programmatically hide/display them (by manipulating the `visible` property). You can similarly change the labels and data-bindings at runtime.  This may seem like a hack, but is a valid way of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: thats great advice, really appreciate you taking the time Noahlz

Answer (score 0):

if you have a table or query containing all the questions for a given client, you can also display a continuous subform with a hidden textbox (ClientID), a textbox (Question) and a Checkbox (answer), in order to display all questions with a checkbox.

Your 'main-form' will basically only contain a Combobox in order to select your client, then you can link the clientID of the main-form (Combobox value) with the ClientID of your sub-form and MS Access will do the rest, with no need to code your business logic.

In this way you can, if needed, also store your answers in your database, have a nice User Interface and a dynamic design with no hard-coded questions...